# specify optional parameter windows form control vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I need to send a subroutine a Windows Form control name as optional parameter

e.g.

```
Sub putdebug(ByVal str As String, Optional ByVal ctrl As ListBox = lbSystem)

..output to different lisboxes depending on ctrl name, default to lbSystem if not specified.
```

But the lbSystem is getting underlined and "Constant Expression Required" is error.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
Sub putdebug(ByVal str As String, Optional ByVal ctrl As ListBox = nothing)
    If IsNothing(ctrl) Then
        ctrl = lbSystem
    End If
End Sub
```

VB wont allow you to assign a value to the optional parameter directly.

Comment: It's so sad that I instantly knew what your user name meant. :)

Comment: You're one of the only people who does! Spent my whole childhood typing it in :)

Comment: Had to put "If IsNothing(ctrl) Then" but that worked! Thanks.  I'm off to drink some Duff Beer.

Comment: haha glad it helped - ill update the answer with your changes.